# Overlap image on div and make half of it invisible

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make the image `70% visible` stick with the `bottom` and the rest of it `invisible` behind the div. I follow the tutorial with `z-index 10` `position absolute` and `overflow:hidden`. but the image still show and overlap on other div. Could you help me? thanks!

HTML

```
<div class="screenshot search">
  <div class="container container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="./img/sc-search@2.jpg" alt="pencarian"/>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h3>
          search
        </h3>
        <p>
          test
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
        .screenshot {
      padding: 6em 0;
      height: auto;
    }

.screenshot img {
  width: 400px;
  max-width: 90%;
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.search {
  background-color: #fafafa;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot with the expected result? Also, can you create a working [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)?

Comment: Have you tried putting the image as a background (in the CSS)?

Comment: You want to hide top 30% of the image with div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are loads of methods to do what you want if I understand right - (a screenshot would help, also if you are including "working code" include a JS fiddle or codepen link) then the example below has working overlap of your content div and the image.

```
  <div class="screenshot search">
      <div class="container container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
               <div class="wrap">
                   <div class="col-md-6 image-wrap">
                       <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.navipedia.net/images/a/a9/Example.jpg" alt="pencarian"/>
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-md-6 content">
                       <h3>search</h3>
                       <p>test</p>
                   </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>

.screenshot {
    padding: 6em 0;
    height: auto;
}

.wrap {
    position:relative;
}

.screenshot img {
    width: 400px;
    max-width: 90%;
    z-index: ;
    position: absolute;
}

.image-wrap {
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    height: 200px;
}

.content {
    display:block;
    background:white;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
 }

 .search {
    background-color: #fafafa;
 }
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vvgk0bt8/)

[Read about Z-index here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/)